# Trying to iterate through two collections

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iteration

I am trying to create a snippet of code that has 2 arrays, one with fruit names one with human names, when ran, I want it to go through each fruit, and each name, e.g "Hello my name is x and I like the fruit x."

When I first wrote the code, I could get it to say one name, but no fruit, and I didnt have an `i++` increment so it didnt go through the collection of names, only the first value. This is the code so far

```
var fruitNames = ["Banana","Apple","Watermelon","Kiwi Fruit"]; 
var peopleNames = ["Nathan","Allie","Chris","Charlie"];

var i =0;

while (i < fruitNames.length < peopleNames.length) {
    
    alert("Hello my name is ")+(peopleNames[0])+("and I like the fruit ")+(fruitNames[0]);
    i++

}
```

Comment: `i` is the index of the array so you need to use that in your array selection: `peopleNames[i]` and `fruitNames[i]`. And just use the length of one array in your condition `i < fruitNames.length`.

Comment: In general, you should make sure the lengths of the arrays are equal. But you can check two lengths by using logical and operator: `(i < fruitNames.length && i < peopleNames.length)`, and then use `i` as an index instead of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way. You really only care about the number of people so long as there's enough fruit.

```js
let fruitNames = ["Banana", "Apple", "Watermelon", "Kiwi Fruit"];
let peopleNames = ["Nathan", "Allie", "Chris", "Charlie"];


peopleNames.forEach((people, index) => {
  if (!fruitNames[index]) return;
  alert(`Hello my name is ${people} and I like ${fruitNames[index]}`);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is use `for-loop` like:

```js
var fruitNames = ["Banana", "Apple", "Watermelon", "Kiwi Fruit"];
var peopleNames = ["Nathan", "Allie", "Chris", "Charlie"];

for (let i = 0; i < fruitNames.length; i++) {
    console.log('Hello my name is ' + peopleNames[i] + ' and i like the fruit ' + fruitNames[i]);
}
```

Or `forEach` like:

```js
var fruitNames = ["Banana", "Apple", "Watermelon", "Kiwi Fruit"];
var peopleNames = ["Nathan", "Allie", "Chris", "Charlie"];

peopleNames.forEach((value,index) =>{
  console.log('Hello my name is ' + value + ' and i like the fruit ' + fruitNames[index]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Three problems with your code.

First, `alert` displays just what's in the brackets, so create a variable to store the message you want to store then put the entire message in the brackets.

Second, to display a particular value in the array, put the index `i` in the square brackets.

```js
while(cond){
  var msg = 'Hello my name is ' + peopleNames[i] + ' and I like the fruit ' + fruitNames[i];
  alert(msg);
  i++;
}
```

Third, I don't know what you're trying to achive with the condition `(i < fruitNames.length < peopleNames.length)` but that's not valid javascript. If you want to loop to whichever is longer, your condition could be `while(i < Math.max(fruitNames.length, peopleNames.length))`, this will give `undefined` when you try to access the non-existent values in the shorter array. If you want to loop to whichever is shorter, your condition could be `while(i < Math.min(fruitNames.length, peopleNames.length))`, this will not show some values in the longer array.

With these changes, your code will look like below:

```js
var fruitNames = ["Banana","Apple","Watermelon","Kiwi Fruit"]; 
var peopleNames = ["Nathan","Allie","Chris","Charlie"];

var i = 0;
while (i < Math.min(fruitNames.length, peopleNames.length)) {
  var msg = 'Hello my name is ' + peopleNames[i] + ' and I like the fruit ' + fruitNames[i];
  alert(msg);
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a super short version. It does a countdown on array length, which means we run the arrays in `.reverse()`

```js
let f = ["Banana", "Apple", "Watermelon", "Kiwi Fruit"].reverse(), p = ["Nathan", "Allie", "Chris", "Charlie"].reverse(), pl = p.length
while (pl-- > 0) console.log(`Hello my name is ${p[pl]} and I like ${f[pl]}`);

// OR change `console.log` --> `alert`
```